# How to properly validate a date using regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a date input (YYYY-MM-DD) with following rules:

1. Given date must be no earlier than 1.9.2019 and no later than 31.12.2019
2. Date must be valid. For example, there are 30 days in September and 31 days in October.

I have tried (just for one month to begin with):

```
/^\d{4}\-\d[09]\-(d0[0-2]|1[0-9])|(d[30])$/i
```

But that does not work. Could I have some advise?

Comment: Your date input  format is different then the limits

Comment: @JustKhaithang It is, I'm trying to get it working just for one month first, then add the year limitation etc.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this in regex only?

Comment: @zoharcochavi Would be definitely easier to write JavaScript function to do that, but it is a school assignment, purpose of which is to learn regex. Unfortunately I have not been able to solve it by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory disclaimer: Regex is not a good tool for this problem; it would be far easier to just *parse the date* and then check if it lies in the desired range. But since this is a purely academic problem...

Let's start by **only solving for October**:

```
/^2019-10-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$/
```

Notes:

- I have **hardcoded** 2019, because the task does not consider any other years.
- I have **hardcoded** October (10), for now.
- I am allowing 01, 02, ... 09, 10, 11, ..., 19, 20, 21, ... 29, 30, 31 for the day. Because it's October.

Now let's expand this to work for **December**, because that's the only other month between September-December with 31 days:

```
/^2019-1[02]-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$/
```

All I've done here is replace `10` with `1[02]` to allow "12" as well as "10" for the month.

Now, how can we make it work for a month with *30 days*, like September? Well, there are many ways you might try to be "clever" about it, but let's just keep it simple and wrap the whole thing in a group:

```
/^2019-(1[02]-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])|09-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))$/
```

Here I've mostly-copied the previous implementation, except for the last part: I'm only allowing `30` but not `31`.

And finally, let's update this one last time to accept 09 **or** 11 as a 30day month:

```
/^2019-(1[02]-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])|(09|11)-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))$/
```

And there you go.

Comment: If you wanted this to work for other months, or other years (especially leap years!!) then this regex will get insanely complicated. But as I said originally, it would be extremely unusual to solve this problem with regex in the real world.

Comment: More specific than mine and correctly read, I suppose +1

Comment: @TomLord I absolutely agree that this could be solved easier with programming language, but exercises such as this exist. Very good answer with all the explanation, huge thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I really encourage you to learn regular expressions, though this is really solved far easier using a programming language. That being said, you could first use a *verbose* expression (not supported by `JS`) and then strip out the whitespaces.

```
^
2019-
    (?:
        (?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])-(?:0?\d|[12]\d|3[01])) # months with 31 days
        |
        (?:(?:0?[469]|11)-(?:0?\d|[12]\d|30))         # months with 30 days
        |
        (?:0?2-(?:0?\d|1\d|2[0-8]))                   # february
    )
$
```

*Hint*: This validates all possible dates within 2019.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WNIhjE/1/) and for the [**`JavaScript` equivalent**](https://regex101.com/r/WSFcDu/1).

Comment: You missed the requirement: *"no earlier than 1.9.2019 and no later than 31.12.2019"*, and this also accepts `00` as a valid day.

Comment: @TomLord: You are absolutely right, overread this.

Comment: Also, contrary to how I interpreted the question, you're accepting single-digit days and months. I'm not 100% sure what the expectation is here.

Comment: @TomLord: I added a hint for the OP. I'd not use it anyway. Single-digit days might be accepted or not.